# Google Wallet : No forms of payment available

Tags: android, android-pay

I'm new to developing Android apps and some apps of mine are paid.
5 people have bought my app till now.
Google Wallet notices that "You have no valid forms of payment available.
This account has no valid form of payment.
Please specify a form of payment in order to get paid".
But when I clicked in "specify a form of payment" then I got the message "No forms of payment available".

So I wonder: Is it normal?
How much is the minimum payout amount in order for me to be eligible for a payout at the end of my payment circle?
I'm Vietnamese.

Thanks for your attention!

Comment: did you find the solution for this? I had this one too!

Comment: Yeah I did. There is a button named "Add an account" at the top of the page ( the page after clicking the text "specify a form of payment"). Just fill the form.

Comment: Thank you so much. However, in Viet Nam, there's no "Routing number", how I can fill that field?

Comment: Google Wallet doesn't support Vietnamese developer to get paid. The only way is that you fill the bank's information of your friend in some supported countries. The countries which were supported by Google are listed here: https://support.google.com/googleplay/android-developer/answer/150324?hl=en

Comment: Hi, i have the same problem. You mean can add a credit or debit card of friend in support country?

Comment: Yes, This is the only thing you can do.

Comment: What do those fields mean ? IBAN ? BIC ?

Comment: FYI, Vietnam is supported now https://support.google.com/googleplay/android-developer/table/3539140?hl=en

Answer (score 0):

Go to https://wallet.google.com/merchant then press Payment settings and then select add payment form. You'll need your IBAN and BIC codes of your bank in order to recieve payments